# apache stopped unexpectedly

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

Suddenly I found apache on my server is stopped !! I don't know the reason
I found those 2 lines on apache error_log and don't know if they are related to the problem happened or not

```
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 1428:tid 139958315632512] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

[core:warn] [pid 1428:tid 139958315632512] AH00045: child process 27440 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
```

I just restart apache and it works.but this is very serious
What is the problem?
Can I set apache to restart if fail without prompt (automatically)

the server is centos 7 and apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6 and using centos web panel
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39272874/1068283

Comment: It is simply trying to restart as a form of garbage collection, but finding that the restart is taking too long.  I wonder how busy your system is?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: Yes, you can automatically restart Apache if it fails. In your systemd unit file you can add `Restart=always`

docs here: 
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=

Of course, this is not a solution but a mask for the problem. You should look into what is causing apache to shutdown.

Comment: OK what is the cause or how I can find it?

Comment: sorry where that systemd unit file in centos 7 located

Comment: Debugging your application is out of scope for a server fault answer, i think. Although, SIGWINCH is a graceful shutdown. Are you sure you or someone didn't stop the service.


Unit file should be here. `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service`

Comment: no file on that location actually

Comment: So do some investigation. `rpm -ql httpd | grep service`

Comment: thanks for you help. sorry one last thing. which log or file i can figure or debug that error.

Comment: @Macnux I would be more interested in finding out which situations apache will exit with `caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully`, rather than a specific log file. It is weird for Apache to log such a signal: `The SIGWINCH signal is sent to a process when its controlling terminal changes its size (a window change).` You should do some research on this.

Comment: weird for me too. don't have any clue